# Linear Algebra Problem about Direct Sums, Kernel and Image.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space, $W$ a subspace of $V$ and $T : V \to V$ a linear operator. Suppose $V = \text{Im } T \oplus W$ and $W$ is $T$-invariant. I have to prove that

(a) $W \subseteq \text{Ker }T$, where $\text{Ker }T$ is the kernel of $T$.

(b) If $V$ is finite dimensional, then $W = \text{Ker }T$.

For (a), I take $w \in W$, and I have prove that $T(w)=0$. Since $W$ is $T$-invariant, then $T(w) \in W$. I really don't know what's next, because I don't know how to use the fact that $V = \text{Im } T \oplus W$. Can I say  $W = \text{Im } T \oplus V$ from this fact? Also, I don't have any idea of how to prove (b). Any hints or ideas will be very appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a) Since $V = \operatorname{im} T \oplus W$, then $\operatorname{im} T \cap W = \{0\}$. To see why, let $v \in \operatorname{im} T \cap W$. We have $v = v + 0 = 0 + v$. $v$ can be uniquely written as the sum of two vectors in each of $\operatorname{im} T$ and $W$. Therefore we must have $v = 0$. Now let $w \in W$. Since $T w \in W$ and $T w \in \operatorname{im} T$, it follows that $T w = 0$ and $w \in \ker T$.

b) We have $\dim V = \dim \operatorname{im} T + \dim \ker T = \dim \operatorname{im} T + \dim W$. Thus $\dim \ker T = \dim W$. Since $W \subset \ker T$, it follows that $\ker T = W$.

Comment: Sorry I'm a little confused. Is $V=W_1 \oplus W_2$ if and only if $V=W_1+W_2$ and $W_1 \cap W_2 = \{0\}$ a theorem for any vector space $V$ or do we have to prove this for a particular $V$?, and also, if it's valid for all $V$, can we take it as the definition of direct sum? so, we wouldn't have to prove that for every particular $V$?

Comment: @Twink It is valid for any vector space. See for example theorem 1.9 in Linear Algebra Done Right. In fact, my proof above holds with little change for any vector space. How do you define the direct sum?

Comment: You don't have to prove that $\operatorname{im}T\cap W=\{0\}$, because it's assumed by hypothesis when writing $V=\operatorname{im}T\oplus W$.

Comment: @egreg It really depends on how you define the direct sum. It looks like Twink has a different definition. Of course, the definitions are equivalent as shown by the proof I've provided.

Comment: @Twink Please tell us how you define it. My answer assumes the definition of $V = W_1 \oplus W_2$ is $V = W_1 + W_2$ and each vector in $V$ can be *uniquely* written as the sum of a vector in $W_1$ and a vector in $W_2$. Again, the definitions are equivalent as shown in my answer.

Comment: @AymanHourieh I have the same definition that you have. But I was confused because in the book I'm reading (Linear Algebra of Lang) they prove that if $V=W_1+W_2$ and $W_1 \cap W_2 = \{0\}$ then $V=W_1 \oplus W_2$, but they don't mention the converse, that's why I wasn't sure it was equivalent.